# Toggle checkbox in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to toggle the checked attribute on clicking the checkbox/button. How to do it?

```
var process = [
        { id: 0, name: "ONe", status: false },
        { id: 1, name: "two", status: false },
        { id: 2, name: "three", status: false },
        { id: 3, name: "four", status: false },
        { id: 4, name: "five", status: false },
        { id: 5, name: "six", status: false },
    ];

{process.map((eachProc) => {
                            const { id, name, status } = eachProc;
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <div key={id}>
                                        <h3>{name}</h3>
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked={status} />
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                status = !status;
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            Select
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </>
                            );
                        })}
```

Here the error coming is that status is constant.

Comment: use `useState(process)` and then toggle state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `process` like a `state`:

```
const [process, setprocess] = useState([
    { id: 0, name: "ONe", status: false },
    { id: 1, name: "two", status: false },
    { id: 2, name: "three", status: false },
    { id: 3, name: "four", status: false },
    { id: 4, name: "five", status: false },
    { id: 5, name: "six", status: false },
]);
```

Then, add a function hange when you click:

```
  const onClick = (id) => {
    setprocess(
      process.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, status: !item.status } : item
      )
    );
  };
```

Finally, add `onClick` to your `button` and `checkbox`:

```
  {process.map((eachProc) => {
    const { id, name, status } = eachProc;
    return (
      <>
        <div key={id}>
          <h3>{name}</h3>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={status} onClick={() => onClick(id)} />
          <button onClick={() => onClick(id)}>Select</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  })}
```

Answer (score 0):

need the state to manage your data, like blew. [see demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wildflower-8w8s9?file=/src/App.js:0-1068)

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [process, setProcess] = React.useState([
    { id: 0, name: "ONe", status: false },
    { id: 1, name: "two", status: false },
    { id: 2, name: "three", status: false },
    { id: 3, name: "four", status: false },
    { id: 4, name: "five", status: false },
    { id: 5, name: "six", status: false }
  ]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {process.map((eachProc) => {
        const { id, name, status } = eachProc;
        return (
          <>
            <div key={id}>
              <h3>{name}</h3>
              <input type="checkbox" checked={status} />
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setProcess((old) =>
                    old.map((item) =>
                      item.id === id ? { ...item, status: !status } : item
                    )
                  );
                }}
              >
                Select
              </button>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```